# FFmpeg: how to concat 2 videos? (1 with no audio tracks, 1 with 2 audio tracks)?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

ffmpeg -i NoAudio.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts

ffmpeg -i 2Audio.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts

ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4

My output.mp4 ends up with only 1 Audio. What am I missing?

Comment: You'll need to add dummy audio to the first file.

Comment: how to add dummy audio to the first file?